# Capture a particular layout Screenshot or save a particular layout in a different Activity Imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I want to capture or save a particular layout and display in another layout  Imageview

I save one RelativeLayout with three ImageViews.
In these ImageViews, I set three different images from the camera or Gallery.
After I set them, I want that this RelativeLayout is Shown in another Activity's  Imageview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture screenshot of your layout on some event. use below code. and send it using intent to next activity.

```
yourlayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
 Bitmap myBitmap = yourlayout.getDrawingCache();

 Intent intent=new Intent(this,NextActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("data", myBitmap )
 startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to me there is not any easy way to pass layout to another activity in android.
What you can do is convert your images to bitmap and then send bitmap to an another activity via intent because a Bitmap implements Parcelable.

For example

```
intent.putExtra("data", bitmap)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
RelativeLayout relative= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.allview);
if (tabLayout != null) {
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(tabLayout.getWidth(),
            tabLayout.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas b = new Canvas(image);
    relative.draw(b);
}
```